# Возврат выбранных значений из диалогового окна Toplevel в поле listbox основного окна Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Пишу небольшой GUI для обработки данных, появилась задача из списка значений, представленного в поле `result_listbox` окна `Toplevel()` 
вернуть выделенные данные в `listbox` главного окна интерфейса.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


search_result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

class Toplevel(object):

     def __init__(self, parent, search_result):
        self.toplevel = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.search_result = search_result

        result_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.toplevel, width=482, height=285, text="Found Result",
                                      relief=tk.RIDGE)
        result_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)
        result_frame.grid_propagate(False)


        result_label = ttk.Label(result_frame, text="List:")
        result_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        result_listbox = tk.Listbox(result_frame, selectmode=tk.EXTENDED, width=65, height=10,
                                    font="Courier 9", bg="#ADD8E6", fg="#191970")
        result_listbox.grid(row=2, rowspan=3, column=1, columnspan=3,
                            sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S, pady=3)

        add_button = ttk.Button(result_frame, text="Add",
                                command=lambda: add())
        add_button.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        close_button = ttk.Button(result_frame, text="Close", command=lambda: self.toplevel.destroy())
        close_button.grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=tk.E)

        for element in search_result:
            result_listbox.insert(0, element)

        def add():

            list_numbers = list(result_listbox.get(0, "end"))

            index = list(result_listbox.curselection())

            selected_numbers = []
            for i in index:
                selected_numbers.append(list_numbers[i])

            print(selected_numbers)

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Click me!", command=self.on_click)
        self.button.pack()

        listbox = tk.Listbox(self, selectmode=tk.EXTENDED, width=65, height=10,
                             font="Courier 9", bg="#ADD8E6", fg="#191970")
        listbox.pack()

    def on_click(self):

        result = Toplevel(self, search_result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Не могу сообразить как вернуть сформированный список `selected_numbers` из диалогового окна и для вставки в поле `listbox` основного окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно записать выбранный элементы в атрибут вашего класса `Toplevel`  и добавить ожидание уничтожения виджета диалогового окна с помощью метода [`wait_window()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_window-method). Примерно так:

```
class Toplevel(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, search_result):
        ...
        self.selected_numbers = []

        def add():

            list_numbers = list(result_listbox.get(0, "end"))

            index = list(result_listbox.curselection())

            selected_numbers = []
            for i in index:
                selected_numbers.append(list_numbers[i])

            print(selected_numbers)
            self.selected_numbers = selected_numbers


class Example(tk.Frame):
    ...

    def on_click(self):
        dialog = Toplevel(self, search_result)
        dialog.toplevel.wait_window()
        print('Selected:', dialog.selected_numbers)
```

Можно также добавить метод ожидания результата, который сам и возвращает результат (скрываем детали реализации):

```
class Toplevel(object):
     def __init__(self, parent, search_result):
        ...

        self.selected_numbers = []

        def add():

            list_numbers = list(result_listbox.get(0, "end"))

            index = list(result_listbox.curselection())

            selected_numbers = []
            for i in index:
                selected_numbers.append(list_numbers[i])

            print(selected_numbers)
            self.selected_numbers = selected_numbers

    def wait_for_result(self):
        self.toplevel.wait_window()
        return self.selected_numbers


class Example(tk.Frame):
    ...

    def on_click(self):
        dialog = Toplevel(self, search_result)
        print('Selected:', dialog.wait_for_result())
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно!