# Как в основном коде получить текст из Entry дочернего диалогового окна

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

При нажатии на кнопку запускается функция, которая запускает окно TopLevel. На нем есть Entry и кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку, функция должна будет возвращать текст из entry.
Пробовал код:

```
def inputBox(win):
    dop = tk.Toplevel(win)
    dop.geometry('200x60')    
    label = tk.Label(dop, text='Введите тираж')
    label.pack()
    inpt = tk.Entry(dop)
    inpt.pack()
    Button = tk.Button(dop, text='ок', command = return inpt.get())
    Button.pack()
res = inputBox(win)
#
#
#
#Описание основной формы
```

Однако он не работает(Просит заменить command = на command ==, что как то не логично). Как это правильно сделать

Comment: Вроде бы просто должно быть `Button = tk.Button(dop, text='ок', command = inpt.get)`, нет?

Comment: @SergBocharov не работает.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Возврат выбранных значений из диалогового окна Toplevel в поле listbox основного окна Tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1008745/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике нажатия на кнопку "ок" нужно записать введенную строку в переменную функции `input_box` и закрыть дочернее окно, в самой функции `input_box` дождаться закрытия дочернего окна (метод [`wait_window`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_window-method)), и вернуть значение этой переменной:

```
import tkinter as tk


def input_box(win):
    dop = tk.Toplevel(win)
    # dop.geometry('200x60')    
    label = tk.Label(dop, text='Введите тираж')
    label.pack()
    inpt = tk.Entry(dop)
    inpt.pack()

    result = None  # Значение по-умолчанию (будет возвращено, например, если закрыть дочернее окно через крестик)
    def callback():
        nonlocal result  # nonlocal говорит, что переменная result является переменной внешней функции (в данном случае inputBox)
        result = inpt.get()
        dop.destroy()  # закрываем окно

    Button = tk.Button(dop, text='ок', command=callback)
    Button.pack()

    # Три строки ниже нужны, чтобы пока существует второе диалоговое окно, основное окно блокировалось 
    # (чтобы дочернее окно было модальным)
    dop.transient(win)
    dop.grab_set()
    dop.focus_set()

    dop.wait_window()  # ждем закрытия окна
    return result

    
win = tk.Tk()

def show_result():
    res = input_box(win)
    label_result.config(text=res)


tk.Button(text="Show input box", command=show_result).pack()
label_result = tk.Label()
label_result.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: В python функции можно описывать в других функциях? не знал... Благодарю

Comment: @BereskletValalal, да. Не всегда это действительно нужно, но иногда полезно.

Comment: В данном случае если сделать функцию `callback` отдельной, то придется делать глобальную переменную для передачи значения из текстового поля. Использование глобальных переменных - это всегда большой минус. Ну или делать через классы и передавать значение через поле объекта, но это усложнит код.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
def inputBox(win):
    dop = tk.Toplevel(win)
    dop.geometry('200x60')    
    label = tk.Label(dop, text='Введите тираж')
    label.pack()
    inpt = tk.Entry(dop)
    inpt.pack()
    inpt.focus_set()
    def callback():
        return inpt.get()
    Button = tk.Button(dop, text='ок', command = callback)
    Button.pack()
res = inputBox(win)
```

Comment: Это нерабочий код, res всегда будет None, и будет возвращено сразу после вызова функции, без ожидания нажатия на "ок" или закрытия окна.